# Jwt tokens authorization is not working

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, authorization, owin, jwt

I'm trying to create Jwt token authorization. For this purpose I have issuer part with the code like that:

```
public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] {"*"});
    Users user;
    using (var db = new UserStore())
    {
        user = Task.Run(()=> db.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password, context.ClientId)).Result;
    }
    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect");
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Roles.Name));

    var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {
            "audience", context.ClientId ?? string.Empty
        }
    });
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
    context.Validated(ticket);
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

And "resource" part that should accept bearer token:

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var issuer = SiteGlobal.Issuer;
    var audience = SiteGlobal.Audience;
    var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(SiteGlobal.Secret);
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
    new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
        IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
        {
            new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
        }
    });
}
```

As far as I can see issued token are valid (I did validation on jwt.io), so the problem is somehwere else. When I'm sending token in Postman with the call to controller protected by `[Authorize]` attribute it always return 401 code. Could you please advise how to fix this?

P.S. This is how I implement custom Jwt fortmat:

```
public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
{
    if (data == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
    }
    string audienceId = data.Properties.Dictionary.ContainsKey(AudiencePropertyKey) ? data.Properties.Dictionary[AudiencePropertyKey] : null;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(audienceId)) throw new InvalidOperationException("AuthenticationTicket.Properties does not include audience");
    Audience audience;
    using (var store = new AudienceStore())
    {
        audience = Task.Run(()=> store.FindAudience(audienceId)).Result;
    }
    var symmetricKeyAsBase64 = audience.Base64Secret;
    var signingKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(symmetricKeyAsBase64));
    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);
    var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
    var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingCredentials);
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);
    return jwt;
}
```

P.S. Guys, I'm so sorry, but I forgot to explain that "issuer" part of code that's standalone application, meanwhile "audience" is protected web api. That's two different appliactions running independently.

Comment: Wouldn't http://security.stackexchange.com/a/128882/131820 help You?

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Is there problem with headers, I will receive something like bad request but not unathorized.

Comment: I got no exp with `jwt`, only with `REST` queries via URL, where request header `Authorization : Basic <encrypted user:pass>` was needed & if something was wrong about that (pass/name/syntax), it threw 401 to me.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved That is what you would use for basic authentication, not JWT. JWT requires an `Authorization: Bearer <jwt>` format.

Comment: Can you please make sure the 'SiteGlobal.Issuer' and '_issuer' have the same value (case sensitive)

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when I setup JWT and kept getting 401s.  Try changing the order in your startup class so that ConfigureOAuth is done before anything else.  That solved it for me (Asp.Net Core WebAPI).

Answer (score 4):

In Postman ensure you are sending the authorization header using the following format:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

[image: Postman Authorization Header]

Ensure that you leave the Authorization tab set to `Type: No Auth`.

If you continue to have issues, set a breakpoint in your `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` and see if it gets to that point. Also consider overriding the [ValidateClientAuthentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserverprovider.validateclientauthentication(v=vs.113).aspx) method of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` which should get called prior to `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` if you want to debug earlier in the chain of events.

Comment: Tha's code from Postman: Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFuZHJleS5zaGVka29AZ21haWwuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiYW5kcmV5LnNoZWRrb0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJyb2xlIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjUyNzk5IiwiYXVkIjoiMDk5MTUzYzI2MjUxNDliYzhlY2IzZTg1ZTAzZjAwMjIiLCJleHAiOjE0ODc3NzIxOTEsIm5iZiI6MTQ4Nzc3MDM5MX0.5GFpvU08CjaS5LTH0vRVFIGuilenkEgVu_aJLma4lPo

Comment: That's question - in "resorce" api I do not have installed Asp.Net identity, as said in this tutorial - http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/comment-page-3/#comment-97300. Method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials I have only on "issuer" part.

Comment: @andrey.shedko you didn't post what you've attempted to run through postman but a 401 suggests that something is not getting through your authorization. Setting break points should allow you to inspect and find the specific point of failure. Does it work if you remove the Authorized attribute and run the request through postman?

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried to run [demo project](https://github.com/tjoudeh/JWTAspNetWebApi) mentioned in [SON Web Token in ASP.NET Web API 2 using Owin](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/comment-page-3/) and all worked as expected.

I noticed that your implementation of `Protect` method differs quite a bit. I would suggest you to compare your implementation to an example given in the article. Try make that work first.

Also please make sure that issuer, audience and secret are same on both servers.

If you provide complete source code I can try to investigate more.